# Automatically convert emails with a Gmail label to PDF and send it to an email address

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I am trying to automatically save the receipts (from Amazon) I receive in GMail to Dropbox. So I have written a script that:

1. automatically select emails with a certain label
2. converts the body of the email to html
3. converts the html to pdf
4. email the pdf of the body and attachment to IFTTT (which automatically saves the attachments to dropbox)
5. deletes the temporary files
6. removes the label

The script works and generates the bodydochtml, but the PDF conversion and email don't work. I am staring at this script for hours. Where is the error in my script?

Thank you!

```
Function send_Gmail_as_PDF(){

  var gLabel  = "#Receipt";
  var thread = GmailApp.search("label:" + gLabel);
  for (var x=0; x<thread.length; x++) {    
     var messages = thread[x].getMessages();  

     for (var y=0; y<messages.length; y++) {  
       var attach  = messages[y].getAttachments();
       var body    = messages[y].getBody(); 

       // Create an HTML File from the Message Body
       var bodydochtml = DocsList.createFile('body.html', body, "text/html")
       var bodyId=bodydochtml.getId()

       // Convert the HTML to PDF
       var bodydocpdf = bodydochtml.getAs('application/pdf').getBytes();

       // Does the Gmail Message have any attachments?
       if(attach.length>0){

       var file=DocsList.createFile(attach[0]);
       var pdf=file.getAs('application/pdf').getBytes();

       var attach_to_send = {fileName: 'pdftest.pdf',
            content:pdf, mimeType:'application/pdf'};
       var body_to_send = {fileName: 'body.pdf',
           content:bodydocpdf, mimeType:'application/pdf'};

       // Send the PDF to any email address
       MailApp.sendEmail('myemail@gmail.com', 
                         'transfer email as pdf : body & attachment', 
                         'see attachment', {attachments:[attach_to_send,body_to_send]});

     // Trash the temporary PDF and HTML files
     file.setTrashed(true);
     DocsList.getFileById(bodyId).setTrashed(true)
     }
   }
}
   // Message Processed; Remove the Google Drive Label
 GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(gLabel)
         .removeFromThread(thread[x]);
}
```

Comment: Are you getting a specific error message? If so, please include it.

Comment: I do get "Cannot find method (class)(class)removeFromThread((class)). (line 46, file "Code")", but nothing about failure to convert to PDF or sending the email.

Comment: @Sergeinsas - Sure, you can create an html file of the body this way. That's not the problem - it's about scoping of variables.

Comment: Keep in mind, you don't actually need to create a temporary file in Google Drive, and then delete it.  Google Apps Script has objects called "Blobs" which are essentially disembodied files which can be used for the same purpose.  So replace DocsList.createFile() with Utilities.newBlob() and it saves you from having to do all the cleanup later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error on line 46 is coming up when `thread[x]` is null. Since you've got that statement outside of the loop that deals with thread[x], you ALWAYS have null. Move the statement into the loop, and this problem is avoided.

Inside your message loop, you check whether the message has any attachments, `if(attach.length>0){` and only continue with the message if it DOES. Wouldn't you want to continue to send an email with only the pdf body? If so, we need to do something about the fixed array in `{attachments:[attach_to_send,body_to_send]}`. Better would be to build an array of attachments as we go, starting with the `body_to_send`. Add:

```
      var attachmentList = [];
      attachmentList.push(body_to_send);
```

Better yet, what if the message has multiple attachments - you'd want them all. To do that, put the attachment handling inside a loop, instead of an `if`, and make sure to move the temp file tidy-up along with it. (That should have been inside the `if` anyway, because if there was no attachment, the `setTrashed()` call would crash.)

```
      // Process all attachments
      for (var att = 0; att < attach.length; att++) {    
        ...
        attachmentList.push(attach_to_send);

        // Trash the temporary file
        file.setTrashed(true);
      }
```

Here's your code, with these changes - it works nicely:

```
function send_Gmail_as_PDF() {

  var gLabel = "#Receipt";
  var thread = GmailApp.search("label:" + gLabel);
  for (var x = 0; x < thread.length; x++) {
    var messages = thread[x].getMessages();

    for (var y = 0; y < messages.length; y++) {
      var attach = messages[y].getAttachments();
      var body = messages[y].getBody();

      // Create an HTML File from the Message Body
      var bodydochtml = DocsList.createFile('body.html', body, "text/html")
      var bodyId = bodydochtml.getId()

      // Convert the HTML to PDF
      var bodydocpdf = bodydochtml.getAs('application/pdf').getBytes();

      var body_to_send = {
        fileName: 'body.pdf',
        content: bodydocpdf,
        mimeType: 'application/pdf'
      };

      var attachmentList = [];
      attachmentList.push(body_to_send);

      // Trash the temporary file
      bodydochtml.setTrashed(true);

      // Process all attachments
      for (var att = 0; att < attach.length; att++) {

        var file = DocsList.createFile(attach[att]);
        var pdf = file.getAs('application/pdf').getBytes();

        var attach_to_send = {
          fileName: 'pdftest.pdf',
          content: pdf,
          mimeType: 'application/pdf'
        };
        attachmentList.push(attach_to_send);

        // Trash the temporary file
        file.setTrashed(true);
      }
    }

    // Send the PDF to any email address
    MailApp.sendEmail('myemail@gmail.com',
      'transfer email as pdf : body & attachment',
      'see attachment', {
        attachments: attachmentList
      });

    // Message Processed; Remove the Google Drive Label
    GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(gLabel)
      .removeFromThread(thread[x]);
  }
}
```

<sub><sup>Code was put through a [prettifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/).</sup></sub>

Answer (score 1):

According to Google developers [page](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/) *DocsList* has been deprecated.

The code in the answers above should use **DriveApp** instead.

```
 function send_Gmail_as_PDF() {

  var gLabel = "#Receipt";
  var thread = GmailApp.search("label:" + gLabel);
  for (var x = 0; x < thread.length; x++) {
    var messages = thread[x].getMessages();

    for (var y = 0; y < messages.length; y++) {
      var attach = messages[y].getAttachments();
      var body = messages[y].getBody();

      // Create an HTML File from the Message Body
      var bodydochtml = DriveApp.createFile('body.html', body, "text/html")
      var bodyId = bodydochtml.getId()

      // Convert the HTML to PDF
      var bodydocpdf = bodydochtml.getAs('application/pdf').getBytes();

      var body_to_send = {
        fileName: 'body.pdf',
        content: bodydocpdf,
        mimeType: 'application/pdf'
      };

      var attachmentList = [];
      attachmentList.push(body_to_send);

      // Trash the temporary file
      bodydochtml.setTrashed(true);

      // Process all attachments
      for (var att = 0; att < attach.length; att++) {

        var file = DriveApp.createFile(attach[att]);
        var pdf = file.getAs('application/pdf').getBytes();

        var attach_to_send = {
          fileName: 'pdftest.pdf',
          content: pdf,
          mimeType: 'application/pdf'
        };
        attachmentList.push(attach_to_send);

        // Trash the temporary file
        file.setTrashed(true);
      }
    }

    // Send the PDF to any email address
    MailApp.sendEmail('myemail@gmail.com',
      'transfer email as pdf : body & attachment',
      'see attachment', {
        attachments: attachmentList
      });

    // Message Processed; Remove the Google Drive Label
    GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(gLabel)
      .removeFromThread(thread[x]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

this code I wrote a while ago does the job if the attachement is in a format that can be converted to pdf.
It gets the message in the last thread and sends both body and attachment only if an attachment is present.
This is a test script.

```
function getAttachAndBody(){
  var firstThread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,1)[0];
  var message = firstThread.getMessages()[0];
  var attach = message.getAttachments();
  var body = message.getBody();//is a string
  var bodydochtml = DocsList.createFile('body.html', body, "text/html")
  var bodyId=bodydochtml.getId()
  var bodydocpdf = bodydochtml.getAs('application/pdf').getBytes();
  if(attach.length>0){
    var file=DocsList.createFile(attach[0])
    var pdf=file.getAs('application/pdf').getBytes();
    var attach_to_send = {fileName: 'pdftest.pdf',content:pdf, mimeType:'application/pdf'};
    var body_to_send = {fileName: 'body.pdf',content:bodydocpdf, mimeType:'application/pdf'};
//    MailApp.sendEmail('xxxxxxx@gmail.com', 'transfer email as pdf : body ', 'see attachment', {attachments:[body_to_send]});
    MailApp.sendEmail('xxxxxxx@gmail.com', 'transfer email as pdf : body & attachment', 'see attachment', {attachments:[attach_to_send,body_to_send]});
    file.setTrashed(true);
    DocsList.getFileById(bodyId).setTrashed(true)
    }
}
```